# how can i access the objects in different view functions

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

i am trying to create a header.html to create a header for all pages and i want to create a dropdown for navigate b/w pages and i want to get the title from model i have two view here
one for home page and for header page
home page view:

```
def homepage(request):

aboutinfo = aboutpage.objects.all()
servicesinfo = services.objects.all()
programinfo = prgm.objects.all()

return render(request, 'index.html', {'aboutinfo': aboutinfo, 'servicesinfo': servicesinfo, 'programinfo': programinfo})
```

header view

```
def header(request):

info = services.objects.all()
return render(request, 'header.html', {'info':info})
```

when i tried the info its not working and i tried the service info from home page it working only index page`

```
         <li class="menu-has-children"><a href="#services">All Services</a>
        <ul>
          {% for services in /* what is here */.all %}
          <li><a href="{% url 'details' services.slug %}">{{ services.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
     </li>
```

Comment: {% for services in servicesinfo.all %}

Comment: yes i tried that but only working in index page not in header page

Comment: if you want in header page you have to add servicesinfo = services.objects.all() there with context also

Answer (score 0):

try to put parenthesis after all

```
info = services.objects.all()
```

Comment: that's because you are returning object into header.html try to access it there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

*views.py*

```
def header(request):
    services = services.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'header.html', {'services':services})
```

*header.html*

```
<ul>
    {% for service in services %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'details' service.slug %}">{{ service.title }}</a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```